# Maximizing the frobenius norm subject to constraints $\underset{\mathbf{S}}{\text{maximize }} \|\mathbf{S}\|_F^2$

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, constraints

IF $\mathbf{X=AS}$ where $\mathbf{X} \in R_+^{n \times m}$, $\mathbf{A} \in R_+^{n \times r}$ are known variable and $\mathbf{S} \in R_+^{r \times m}$ is unknown variable, How to solve the below problem,

$\underset{\mathbf{S}}{\text{maximize }} \|\mathbf{S}\|_F^2$

subject to $\mathbf{X=AS}$, $\mathbf{S}\succeq 0$, $\|\mathbf{S}\|_1=1$

I will appreciate your help as I am not from mathematics background. I have tried many formulation to suit the available algorithms, but I could not manage to end up with any. At Least tips and suggestion with guideline to solve similar problem will help greatly.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: The maximization makes your problem difficult to solve as it is a non-convex problem. Standard solvers could solve minimizaton which would be a convex problem.

Comment: That's right. It is not, in fact, a convex optimization problem.

Comment: If I rephrase the problem as $\min -\|s\|_F^2$ subject to above constraints, will that be possible? 

Or if I say that I want to maximize the frobenius norm of S subject to those constraints anyhow, what should be the way to go?  

Thanks for your comment.